# Make particle hair affected by gravity?

Tags: particles, hair

Using Blender 2.81, is there a way to make dynamic particle hair fall and hang like in real life, affected by gravity?

I have made a scalp with hair and combed it how I want it. If I then enable Hair Dynamics and rotate the scalp 40 degrees, the hair will also rotate 40 degrees and stay that way (after jiggling a bit, back to it's combed state). But in reality, the hair should keep hanging straight down due to gravity even when the scalp is rotated.

Is there a way to achieve this effect?

[image: Screenshot of current settings]

Comment: Can you include a screen shot/s of the settings. Sounds like Stiffness is to high

Comment: I have added a screenshot where you can see the settings. As you can see, I have rotated the scalp and the hair is rotated with it and stays in this position. You would expect the hair to hang down along the red line due to gravity.

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

Physic simulations in Blender don't update at any time (and that's a good thing, so you don't melt down your computer and you keep a responsive software as long as you need).

In order to the gravity affect your hairs, you have to start the playback. You have the playback controls buttons on the bottom left of your screenshot.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, all my testing is done with the playback running. You can also see the red cache line in my timeline showing the cached information.

I added weight paint to the particles, since I want the hairs to keep a specific shape, maybe this has something to say? Whenever I start playback and move the scalp, the hairs jiggle according to my settings, but then they settle back in their combed position. I'm wondering if this may not be possible since I need the hair in a combed shape...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem, but you have WAY TOO MUCH "pin goal strength" in your Hair dynamics! With that much pin strength the hair will be glued to the position you gave it when you combed and weighted. Lower that value to something around 0.01 and you might start to see some effect from gravity.

Pin goal strength defines how badly the hair wants to go back to its goal (goal here means what you made it look like with the comb), so you want it very low for flowy hair, and higher for stiff short hair.

Assigning weight only to the roots will also help (or leave the weight alone, works pretty well on default), so that the pin goal strength is applied most strongly to roots but the tips flow freely.